# Finding first N occurrences of regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

So this should be easy but I somehow miss the answer on SO or Python docs.
I am using this code:

```
myregex.findall(source)
```

This produces all matches of myregex as a list.
Now, the problem is that source is long and I only need first 6 occurrences of substring matching myregex. I imagine that it would be much faster if matching process could stop after finding first n occurrences.
How do I do something like:

```
myregex.findall(source, n)
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`re.finditer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
import itertools
for m in itertools.islice(re.finditer(pat, text), 6):
    ...
```

`re.finditer` is a generator that produces `match` objects on demand. You can get the complete match from `m.group(0)`, or individual pattern matches from `m.group(1)` and up.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want performance, use `regex.finditer`

```
def my_find(regex, s, n):
    const = regex.finditer(s)
    return [const.next().groups() for i in range(n)]
```

Or a safer version:

```
def my_find(regex, s, n):
    const = regex.finditer(s)
    ret_val = []
    for i in range(n):
        try:
            ret_val.append(const.next().groups())
        except StopIteration:
            return ret_val
    return ret_val
```

Comment: No, this will still do all the searching. The OP looks for a way to reduce the time spent looking for matches.

Comment: My question is about performance. To do slices on a list you need to calculate whole list first which I want to avoid.

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz Editted answer.